# Writing Nested WHERE clause in ArcGIS Rest API Feature Service

Tags: rest, arcgis, arcgis-server

I'm attempting to query a feature service using a nested WHERE clause. I'm trying to return the record with the highest OBJECTID count, but I'm not sure how to really adapt this to the REST query.
On a feature class i would expect the WHERE clause to look something like;

```
SELECT MAX("OBJECTID") FROM (feature class name)
```

How would one go about adapting this expression to the REST query form for the WHERE clause?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the output statistics value to return this (leave the where clause blank).

```
[{"statisticType":"max","onStatisticField":"OBJECTID", "outStatisticFieldName":"maxobjectid"}]
```